# Error uninstalling, updating and re-installing MySQL on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, installation

I'm trying to uninstall and remove MySQL on Ubuntu 20.04.

If I try to install a new package, in my case `sudo apt-get install putty`, remove or update a package, the terminal complains with

```
 You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     mysql-server-8.0 : Depends: mysql-server-core-8.0 (= 8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) but 8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 is to be installed
     putty : Depends: putty-tools but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So far I've tried `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove mysql mysqld mysql-server mysql-server-core`, updating `mysql-server-core` from 8.0 to 8.0.26, manually deleted all mysql folders and files with `sudo rm -R` from `/root` directory, `sudo apt-get install putty-tools` because its a dependency for putty - everything gives me the same error.

I attempted to stop the mysql service before uninstalling mysql with `service mysql stop` and it gives me this error

```
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
```

My terminal doesn't recognize the `clear` command anymore and it complains with

```
Command 'clear' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install ncurses-bin
```

But then again, when I try to `sudo apt-get install ncurses-bin` or `sudo apt install ncurses-bin`, it gives the MySQL error above. I can't install or uninstall anything.

I've browsed a lot in the past week trying to find an answer for my problem, hence why I'm writing here. Right now its to a point where I want to clean install a new instance of Ubuntu. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? I feel like I'm missing something out.

Comment: Answered on askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/172514/how-do-i-uninstall-mysql

Comment: Nope,  I already tried it. It didn't work. After `sudo systemctl stop mysql` terminal returns `Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.`